# Custom view refresh: postInvalidate vs drawableStateChanged: which one should I use?

Tags: android, android-view

I created a custom progressbar not dissimilar from:
http://weavora.com/blog/2012/02/23/android-progressbar-with-text/
or http://colintmiller.com/2010/10/how-to-add-text-over-a-progress-bar-on-android/

I noticed that during operations relating to canvas, such as canvas.drawText() within an overriden onDraw method, both authors opted to somehow invalidate the state of the view.

One used postInvalidate(), the other drawableStateChanged().

None explained their reasoning.

Can someone shed some light as to which one is the most 'appropriate way' of going forward?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is postInvalidate(), because drawableStateChanged() simply doesn't work, period (ie, onDraw never gets called).